# Need to display custom taxonomy on single page - not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I've looked at several posts on here trying to crack this. I think it's simple for someone who knows more. The details:

Theme: Custom theme built on Roots starter

WP: 3.8.1

Custom Post Type: pre_owned_cars

My custom post types work well - I'm used to doing those. The taxonomy however is tripping me up. I have it working with the code in my functions.php file, but I can't figure out how to display a taxonomy. I've created taxonomy.php and updated permalinks.

Here's my functions.php code for the taxonomy - I'm trying to name the taxonomy "type":

```
// add tags to pages
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_types' );

function register_taxonomy_types() {

$labels = array( 
    'name' => _x( 'Types', 'types' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Type', 'types' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Search Types', 'types' ),
    'popular_items' => _x( 'Popular Types', 'types' ),
    'all_items' => _x( 'All Types', 'types' ),
    'parent_item' => _x( 'Parent Type', 'types' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Type:', 'types' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Type', 'types' ),
    'update_item' => _x( 'Update Type', 'types' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Type', 'types' ),
    'new_item_name' => _x( 'New Type', 'types' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => _x( 'Separate types with commas', 'types' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => _x( 'Add or remove Types', 'types' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => _x( 'Choose from most used Types', 'types' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Types', 'types' ),
);

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,

    'rewrite' => array( 
        'slug' => 'used-cars', 
        'with_front' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true
    ),
    'query_var' => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'types', array('pre-owned-cars'), $args );
}
```

Any help GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Is the taxonomy showing up in the admin area correctly?

Comment: describe "not working". you've named your taxonomy `types`, and given it the slug `used-cars`, so a single term will be `/used-cars/term-name/`. have you created a term and assign it to a post? note that taxonomies aren't like post types- there is no single archive, it's archives for *each term*.

Comment: Okay, so the slug combined with the term is generating a page, but instead of showing the CPTs with this term or taxonomy, it's printing this on the page:                                         wp_list_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'register_taxonomy_type' ) ); wp_list_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'register_taxonomy_type' ) ); (thanks for the help!)

Comment: Per the last comment, your problem appears to be with your theme template-- a PHP syntax error I'd guess. Post the code for that template.

Comment: <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  
               wp_list_categories( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'register_taxonomy_type'
) );
  
     <?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: You know what...I see the problem. So I'm getting the title and link now. Can I pull specific elements of the custom post type that is tagged? I have several meta fields in the CPT and would like to pull them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the taxonomy is registered with your custom post type.
Please check this or may be i'm wrong:
if your custom post type is registered with this name: `'pre_owned_cars'` , your taxonomy registration is incorrect: it should be `register_taxonomy('types', array('pre_owned_cars'), $args);`

Comment: I changed it - thanks! The page is pulling fields from the CPT, but only the basic three, see here: http://www.shopsupercars.com/used-cars/suv/

Comment: I want to display like this: http://www.shopsupercars.com/pre-owned-car-inventory-johnson-city/

Comment: I'm not getting it.. Sorry... Please elaborate once again..

Comment: No problem - thanks for the help. The taxonomy is working, but I want to pull only specific fields from the custom post type the taxonomy is registered to. For example, the CPT is for a car. I want taxonomy.php to display the make, model and year fields of the CPT. Doe that make sense?

Comment: you can print the fields value like this: echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_name', true);